# How to get itemtype on fieldChanged event

Tags: netsuite

I'm selecting a item in sublist item from a purchase order and i need to go in item register, get some informations and put them in current line of purchase order. I need to do this in fieldChanged event (ClientScript).

For to do this, i need to get ItemId (that user selected) and ItemType.

```
function fieldChanged(scriptContext) {

    var currentRec = scriptContext.currentRecord;
    var currentSublist = scriptContext.sublistId;
    var currentField = scriptContext.fieldId;

    if (currentSublist == 'item'){
        if (currentField == 'item'){
            var itemType = currentRec.getCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'itemtype'});
            var itemId = currentRec.getCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'item'});
        }
    }
}
```

The itemId is set to id of item that user has selected.

The itemType is empty and i need to get item type of item that user has selected.

Does someone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `fieldChanged` event is triggered before dependant fields have been populated. You should move your logic to a `postSourcing` event to achieve this.